# SQLite connection w/ Libgdx .Desktop

Tags: java, sqlite, libgdx

Well, I'm trying to use SQLite in my Libgdx game, but don't know how.

`public class Main {     

    public static void main(String[] args){
            LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

                config.title = Game.TITLE;
                config.width = Game.V_WIDTH * Game.SCALE;
                config.height = Game.V_HEIGHT * Game.SCALE;

            new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);   
        }}`

What I need to do in my main? lol
I've been looking for this but, all I can find is related to Android application.

[I already have the driver in my ref libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t1gc.jpg), and connection class..

Comment: Making games is more then just making a game. Knowing Java, knowing how to use additional libraries, read APIs from these libraries. Without this you will find it very difficult, tedious and long journey making a video game. There are numerous ways to use SQLite in Java, numerous libraries and each one has a tutorial on how to use them as well as API documentation.

Comment: @Underbalanced thanks for answer! You are right, but I think I need that someone helps me or link a tutorial since I can't find an explanation on how to properly connect my game with the database... I just find android related within this library..

Comment: When you get a connection answer, then how are you going to know how to use it? Data just doesn't magically get saved into a database. You may or may not need another library to help persist it, or you may have to write all of your own persistence mechanisms. I googled "using sqlite with java" and found plenty! This was the first result.... which is the listed answer..... [SQLite Java Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when using a database with an application, is make a ConnectionFactory, that returns a new connection to the database.

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

   public static Connection getConnection() {
      Connection con = null;

      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db"); //change to whatever db you want

      return con;
   }
}
```

now we have a ConnectionFactory that can pump out connections to our database. Now when we want to interact with the database, you can get the connection appropriately. inside your main, it might look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection con = null;

   String firstName = null, lastName = null;

   try {
      con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM myTable where myId = ?");
      pstmt.setInt(1, /*some id here, ill put this as example:*/ 1234567);

      //execute the query and put into result set so we can get the values.
      ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      //the resultset iterates through rows, by calling next
      if( rs.next() ) //could be while(rs.next()) if expecting multiple rows
      { 
         firstName = rs.getString("firstName"); //column name you want to grab here
         lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
      }
   }  catch(SQLException sqle) {
      sqle.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally {
     try {
        con.close(); //dont forget to close your connection to database!
     } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

You will need to create tables within the SQLite database and insert records before you can do any interactions though, so keep that in mind.